# Cufon not working on server, but working locally

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cufon

I have a project where I am using cufon for font-replacement. The issue is that on my local computer, I am testing it and it is working well. However, once I uploaded it to my hosting, it doesn't work. What could be the problem? Is there any dependency that cufon needs that I am not aware of?

I have uploaded the exact same thing from my test server to the hosting.

Here's the link to the website : http://merlionarowana.com/crm

The "Search Merlion Arowana MerlionTag™" should be changed to another font as well as the home link on the side menu.

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing 404 on this url http://merlionarowana.com/crm/scripts/Quicksand_book.font.js.

Make sure your path is correct.